# The machine "want to" or "wants to"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

As stated in the question: The machine "want to" or "wants to" .. ? 
Shall I add "s" because it refers to it (the machine)? or is shall I omit the "s"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The machine is 3rd person singular so rule is the same as for "it", so:

> The machine wants to...

Comment: Hello, mariachi. As @Reg Dwight has said, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.' / The correct response here is to close-vote. I've used the 'lack of research' option because I'm sure the sister site ELL, which is aimed at learners, would also think it inappropriate.